# Local axios call cannot connect to local .net core API

Tags: asp.net-core, axios, localhost

I am trying to test some performance issues on a .net core API  (VS2019 .net core 2.2)

I can run the API on my local machine using swagger.

The API is called from a ReactJS web app using axios calls which I am running locally. Calling the API located on the Azure servers (dev, test, prod) is successful.

When I call the local API from the web app, the API receives the request and returns a response but it is not received from in the web app. I get this error

> Error: Network Error
> at createError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:149705:15)
> at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:149256:14) {config: {…},
> request: XMLHttpRequest, response: undefined, stack: 'Error: Network
> Error
> at createError (http…ocalhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:149256:14)', message:
> 'Network Error'}

I saw on similar posts that this could be a CORS issue. The API sets up CORS as

```
app.UseCors(policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials());
```

Does anybody have any idea I can try to identify why I cannot connect the web app to the api locally?

Thanks in advance
Hank

Comment: Specifying `AllowAnyOrigin` and `AllowCredentials` is an insecure configuration and can result in cross-site request forgery. The CORS service returns an invalid CORS response when an app is configured with both methods.You could change `AllowAnyOrigin` to `WithOrigins("Specify the send request origin")`.Or you could change `AllowAnyOrigin` to `.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)`.

Comment: @Rena, Thanks. This solved a similar issue with a ,net core 3.1 API but the 2.2 API is still not working - I changed the use cors line to  _app.UseCors(policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000").AllowCredentials());_

Comment: Hi @Rena, both solutions worked for the .net core 3.1 app. I got them working for the 2.2 app by enabling ssl and pointing the web app to the https address.Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying `AllowAnyOrigin` and `AllowCredentials` is an insecure configuration and can result in cross-site request forgery. The CORS service returns an invalid CORS response when an app is configured with both methods.

You could change `AllowAnyOrigin` to `WithOrigins("Specify the send request origin")`.

```
app.UseCors(policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod()
                            .WithOrigins("Specify the send request origin").AllowCredentials());
```

Or you could change `AllowAnyOrigin` to `.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)`:

```
app.UseCors(policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod()
                            .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true).AllowCredentials());
```